# Literary statements that are false as mathematics

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics, big-list

I recently wanted to use
the title of the famous short story
"Everything that Rises must Converge"
in a poem of mine.
However, the mathematician in me
insisted on changing it to
"Everything that Rises, if the rise is bounded, must Converge".

Are there other literary quotations
that are false mathematically,
and how can they be changed to make them true?

Note:
Attempts to use
"To be or not to be"
will be dealt with
most severely.

Comment: Bounded or not, it converges in the extended real line
${\bf R} \cup \{\pm\infty\}$.

Comment: While a nice question, shouldn't it be Community Wiki?

Comment: Just about every use of the word "exponentially" qualifies.

Comment: This doesn't quite work because it takes some fiddling, but many run across this in gradeschool: `Two wrongs don't make a right.` vs `-1 * -1 = 1`

Comment: @Izkata `Two wrongs` is usually interpreted to mean `-1 + -1`, which does indeed fail to make positive 1.

Comment: Interesting that this question of mine was closed two years after it was asked.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Hosea 1:10

> Yet the number of the children of Israel shall be as the sand of the sea, which cannot be measured nor numbered

Both the children of Israel and the sand of the sea are, of course, finite sets.
As a fine grain of sand has a mass of approximately $3.5 \times 10^{-10}$ kg according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28mass%29 , it only takes about 2.5 kg of sand grains to outnumber all the people currently
alive on Earth.  Even for coarse sand, a truckload should suffice.

Comment: Since that is future tense, it could be true eventually.

Comment: Assuming there are about 10^18 grains of sand in the sea, and the surface area of earth is 5 * 10^14 m^2, the density of Isrealites would be 1,960 Isrealites / m^2. In other words, the surface of the earth would be a writhing mass of Isrealites.

Comment: Obviously we need to expand into interstellar space.

Comment: maybe total number ever lived?

Comment: Did Hosea even *read* Archimedes?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sand_Reckoner

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here for you, @trav1s.  http://what-if.xkcd.com/4/

Comment: @SammyBlack, you found the inspiration for my comment!

Comment: @SammyBlack: Given that Hosea was in 8 c. BC and Archimedes was in 3 c it would be rather unlikely had he not been a prophet.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka : And did Archimedes know about Hosea (or other references to the sand of the sea in the Bible)?  Probably not, although the first Greek translations of the Torah appeared around his time.  I suspect that "sand of the sea" similes were common in Mediterranean cultures of those times.

Comment: Are we assuming that "as" here means "the same number as"? If so, why, when the sentence seems to explain that the two entities are being likened on the basis of being immeasurable / uncountable, not on the basis of having the same count?

Comment: The topic is "Literary statements that are false *as mathematics*".  How this verse should be interpreted *not as mathematics* is an entirely different question.

Comment: Was Hosea ignoring the Book of Numbers or was that written after his time?

Comment: @AlonsodelArte What about the Book of Numbers?

Comment: @RobertIsrael e.g., Numbers 2:4, Numbers 2:6, Numbers 2:8, etc.

Comment: Those are talking about a certain time in the past.  Hosea is talking about the future.

Answer (score 45):

A great example of this:

> "Sir, in your otherwise beautiful poem (The Vision of Sin) there is a verse which reads 'Every moment dies a man, every moment one is born.' Obviously this cannot be true and I suggest that in the next edition you have it read 'Every moment dies a man, every moment one-and-one-sixteenth is born.' Even this value is slightly in error but should be sufficiently accurate for the purposes of poetry."
>
> - Charles Babbage, in a letter to Lord Tennyson

Comment: The version of the story I remember reading is that the line originally
read "Every *minute* dies a man, every *minute* a man is born",
and in response to Babbage's critique each "minute" was changed to "moment",
which is not a fixed time interval and thus does not contradict
population growth.

Comment: I would take issue with Babbage's critique, as it does not say "exactly every minute a man is born" - it only establishes that at least one is born every minute. Indeed, I would assert that "moment" is a poor substitute, as one can choose a moment at which there is no man born. Tennyson should have stuck to his original choice.

Comment: Suppose there was one death per minute. In the 19th century, life expectancy at birth was maybe about $16$ million minutes, so that would imply a population of about $16$ million people. The census of 1841 (one year before "The Vision of Sin" was published) recorded the population of England and Wales at $15.9$ million.  Not bad!

Comment: @RobertIsrael What was the birth rate? Also, how does that imply that? I feel like there are unstated assumptions you're making.

Comment: Imagine a single individual who upon his/her death is immediately replaced by a newborn, and this process continues indefinitely.  Let $N(t)$ be the number of deaths from time $0$ to time $t$.  The Renewal Theorem says that with probability $1$, in the long run the average number of deaths per unit time is $\lim_{t \to 0} N(t)/t = 1/\mu$ where $\mu$ is the expected time from birth to death, i.e. the life expectancy at birth.  A constant population of $M$ individuals can be regarded as $M$ copies of this process, so the average number of deaths per unit time would be $M/\mu$.

Answer (score 22):

This one is rather famous:

> **1 Kings 7:23**
>
> Then he made the sea of cast metal. It was round, ten cubits from brim
>   to brim, and five cubits high, and a line of thirty cubits measured
>   its circumference.

Comment: A similar verse appears in 2 Chronicles 4:2.

Comment: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/bibleval.htm

Comment: By "line", it actually refers to a cable of some type (typically something about the thickness of paracord, but may vary). Thus, it is saying that a piece of rope 30 cubits long wraps exactly once around it.

Comment: @AJMansfield Then it should be longer than pi, not shorter. The typical explanation given is either that it was not circular (an ellipse can easily meet this description) or not cylindrical (if it were narrower at the bottom, as a bowl would be, and the circumference were measured there.)

Comment: @Random832 Remember, elasticity. Most cables are longer when stretched, as it would when wrapped around the object, that it would be laid out on the ground for measurement.

Comment: @AJMansfield People back then weren't stupid - if it stretched to any significant degree, they would stretch it for measurement as well.

Comment: @Random832 No, not necessarily. If you didn't have this preconception that 'the ratio between the diameter and the radius always has to be $\pi$, and $\pi$ has to be 3.14...', it might not be readily apparent that the tension required to keep the cable wrapped around the object is deforming to this degree. The accepted value for $\pi$ by Babylonian empire mathematicians was obtained experimentally, and was actually nearer to 3 than the present accepted value.

Comment: I'm not talking about noticing it while measuring the bowl - I'm saying they would have noticed their cord has some give to it just by feeling it stretch, and wouldn't have just laid it on the ground to measure its length.

Comment: @Random832 Actually, that is exactly what they would have done, since that is _the way they did things_, and doing things differently makes the measurement useless when you compare it to other related measurements, such as the circumference of whatever was going to hold it, etc, _exactly the way some professions do today_.

Comment: I always took this just to be an example of the use of significant digits in action rather than false mathematics.

Comment: It's even more entertaining. The thickness of the wall of the basin is given. Compute having measured the inside circumference and outside diameter. The number is astoundingly close for a document that old.

Answer (score 16):

[As I noted 
some years ago](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M55b.02/p8.pdf), an example is the claim by Thomas Carlyle (1795$-$1881, 
in *Sartor Resartus* (c.1833)) that "It is a mathematical fact that 
the casting of this pebble from my hand alters the centre of gravity 
of the universe."  In fact, this echo of John Donne's 
"if a clod be washed away by the sea, Europe is the less"
[[Meditation XVII](http://www.online-literature.com/donne/409/), 1624]
is not a fact of mathematics but an error in physics according to
Newton's Laws (1687): the recoil must exactly cancel out the pebble as the
"centre of gravity of the universe" continues on its unalterable course.

[*Later*] Proposed correction: "It is a mathematical fact that
the casting of this pebble from my hand moves the centre of gravity
of the Earth."

Comment: (but only while the pebble is in flight:
soon it rejoins the Earth, and then we're back where we began.)

Answer (score 7):

From John Green's *The Fault in Our Stars*:

> There are infinite numbers between 0 and 1. There's .1 and .12 and .112 and an infinite collection of others. Of course, there is a bigger infinite set of numbers between 0 and 2, or between 0 and a million.

The problem is that $[0,1]$, $[0,2]$ and $[0,10^6]$ all have the same cardinality of $\mathfrak{c}$, i.e. have the same number of elements :)

Answer (score 6):

> "Reeling and Writhing, of course, to begin with," the Mock Turtle replied; "and then the different branches of Arithmetic--Ambition, Distraction, Uglification, and Derision."

Alice's Adventures in Wonderland, by Lewis Carroll.

Comment: Some may say that this one is accurate...

Answer (score 5):

Would you count sayings as literary? If so, what about

- What goes up must come down.

Some would argue this was proven wrong in a way by Sputnik (or take any modern GEO satellite). A strict reading of your question would dismiss this as a physical constraint, not a false statement in a mathematical sense).

And then, the exponential function (among many others) may disagree.

Comment: Taking the other side, some might say that Sputnik is constantly coming down.  After all, what is orbit but continuous falling?

Comment: So pick Voyager instead...

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps my favorite is the example of **The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy**, a trilogy of five books.

> "If a man will begin with certainties, he shall end in doubts." - Francis Bacon

This would be a very poor website were that to be true.

> "There's no limit to how complicated things can get on account of one thing leading to another." - E. B. White

Okay maybe that one is correct.

Answer (score 3):

From the Matrix revolutions:

> "Everything that has a beginning has an end, Neo." -Agent Smith

Ummmm... what about the natural numbers? And the ordinal numbers? And lets not forget the cardinal numbers. Hell, even $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is a counterexample. In fact, given any totally ordered set $T$ that lacks a greatest element, we can always adjoin a first element.

Answer (score 2):

The test instructions, “Draw a circle around the correct answer.” really means, “Draw a Jordan curve around the correct answer.” - or, even more accurately, “Draw an approximation of a Jordan curve around the correct answer.”

Answer (score 1):

> Two wrongs don't make a right.

Clearly this is a false statement.

If you multiply a negative (a wrong) by another negative, you get a positive (a right).

Comment: But three rights make a left.

Comment: And who told you that the group operation was multiplication? Adding two wrongs, indeed, does not make a right!

Comment: All that says, is that if we let $+$ denote a 'right', $-$ a 'wrong', $S\supseteq\{-,+\}$, and $m:\{+,-\}^2\to S$ the compositing function we are referring to, then the statement simply means that $m(-,-) \ne +$.

Answer (score 1):

The adage, “If you lose an hour in the morning, you’ll be looking for it the rest of the day.”

Admittedly, the inconsistency is due simply to metaphorical usage, but still...

Answer (score 0):

from “Animal Farm”: “...some are more equal than others”

Answer (score 0):

from the poem “Kubla Khan”: “...through caverns measureless to man”

There are unmeasurable sets, but no cavern is unmeasurable.

Answer (score 0):

In ordinary language, a “set” usually means an indexed set (aka “multiset”).

Answer (score 0):

In ordinary language, a “biased” result is considered useless, but in Mathematics (Statistics), a result can be biased, but still useful.